# sqlite3 interface error when binding parameter 1

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to check if a class exists within a "classinfo" database and based on whether it exists or not, will add the details of the class to the database. However, I keep getting and error saying that the parameters for one of the values isnt right.

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            UserID text PRIMARY KEY,
            FName text,
            SName text,
            username text,
            password varchar,
            userType text)""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ClassInfo (
    ClassID text PRIMARY KEY,
    ClassName text,
    Teacher text,
    FOREIGN KEY("Teacher") REFERENCES "users"("UserID"));""")
conn.commit()

        conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        ClassName = (var_classname.get())
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM classinfo WHERE ClassName = ?", (ClassName,))
        data = c.fetchall()
        if len(data) == 0:
            ClassID = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM ClassInfo WHERE ClassID = ?", (ClassID,))
            bruh = c.fetchall()
            if len(bruh) == 0:
                var_insert_classinfo = (ClassID, var_classname, username)
                c.execute('insert INTO ClassInfo (ClassID, ClassName, Teacher)VALUES(?,?,?);', var_insert_classinfo,)
                conn.commit()
                Label(screen6, text = "Successfully registered! Class name is "+ClassName+"", fg = "GREEN", font = ("Calibri",12)).pack()

c.execute('insert INTO ClassInfo (ClassID, ClassName, Teacher)VALUES(?,?,?);', var_insert_classinfo,)
```

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: What is `var_insert_classinfo`? Where is it defined?

Comment: This code gives: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`, fix your indentations